# Retrieve a subset of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix with 200 rows and two columns:

```
     Col1 Col2
  [1,]  470  535
  [2,]  490  522
  [3,]  482  509
  [4,]  473  517
  [5,]  461  524
  [6,]  493  528
  [7,]  498  518
  [8,]  502  530
  [9,]  480  520

 ...
[194,]  513  521
[195,]  500  509
[196,]  501  532
[197,]  517  549
[198,]  501  550
[199,]  504  525
[200,]  493  521
```

I want to cut this Matrix, that I have only the first 10 rows:

```
      [1,]  470  535
      [2,]  490  522
      [3,]  482  509
      [4,]  473  517
      [5,]  461  524
      [6,]  493  528
      [7,]  498  518
      [8,]  502  530
      [9,]  480  520
     [10,]  489  537
```

how can I do that in r?

Comment: `head(YourMatrix, 10)`?

Comment: but if I want to have row 2 till 12, can I use this method too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific question, you can simply use `head`. For your question in the comments, you can use basic `[` extraction:

```
m <- matrix(sequence(100), ncol = 2) ## Sample data

## `head` defaults to returning the first 6 rows...
> head(m)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   51
[2,]    2   52
[3,]    3   53
[4,]    4   54
[5,]    5   55
[6,]    6   56

## ... but has an optional argument if you want to see more....
> head(m, 10)
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1   51
 [2,]    2   52
 [3,]    3   53
 [4,]    4   54
 [5,]    5   55
 [6,]    6   56
 [7,]    7   57
 [8,]    8   58
 [9,]    9   59
[10,]   10   60

## Use basic `[` extracting to get a specific subset
> m[2:12, ]
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    2   52
 [2,]    3   53
 [3,]    4   54
 [4,]    5   55
 [5,]    6   56
 [6,]    7   57
 [7,]    8   58
 [8,]    9   59
 [9,]   10   60
[10,]   11   61
[11,]   12   62
```